# How to use run time generated type in expression tree C#

Tags: c#, expression-trees, reflection.emit, runtime-type

I am building a rule checking algorithm that using expression tree, for the type generated using reflection.emit namespace. For some reason i am not able to get it working.

> Getting the exception "System.ArgumentException: 'Instance property 'Parameter1' is not defined for type 'System.Object''"

I did try creating dynamic type using `expandoObject` instead of `reflection.emit` , it did not work

I appreciate it if anybody can help me to solve the problem. Code sample is given.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace RuleEngine
{

    public class RuleEngine
    {

        public static IEnumerable<RuleOutput> RunRule<T>(IEnumerable<RuleCondition> rules, object targetEntity)
        {
            IEnumerable<RuleOutput> ruleOutput = null;
            foreach (var rule in rules)
            {
                var ruleDetails = rule.RuleConditionDetails;
                rule.RuleConditionDetails.ForEach((item) =>
                {
                    item.ConditionOperatorToApply = GetExpressionOperator(item.ConditionOperator);
                });
                var compiledRules = CompileRule<T>(rule.RuleConditionDetails);

                var foundMatchingRule = compiledRules.All(ruleTemp => ruleTemp(targetEntity));
                if (foundMatchingRule)
                {
                    ruleOutput = rule.RuleConditionOutput;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return ruleOutput;
        }

        private static List<Func<object, bool>> CompileRule<T>(List<RuleConditionDetails> ruleConditionDetailsList)
        {
            var compiledRules = new List<Func<object, bool>>();
            ruleConditionDetailsList.ForEach(ruleConditionDetails =>
            {
                var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
                var binaryExpression = BuildBinaryExpression<T>(ruleConditionDetails, parameterExpression);


                compiledRules.Add(Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>(binaryExpression, parameterExpression).Compile());
            });
            return compiledRules;
        }

        private static Expression BuildBinaryExpression<T>(RuleConditionDetails ruleConditionDetails, ParameterExpression parameterExpression)
        {
            Expression expression = null;
            var leftOperand = MemberExpression.Property(parameterExpression, ruleConditionDetails.RuleParameter);

            ExpressionType expressionType;
            Type operandType = null;
            MethodInfo methodInfo = null;

            if (ExpressionType.TryParse(ruleConditionDetails.ConditionOperatorToApply, out expressionType))
            {
                operandType = typeof(T).GetProperty(ruleConditionDetails.RuleParameter).PropertyType;
                var rightOperand = Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(ruleConditionDetails.ParameterValue, operandType));
                expression = Expression.MakeBinary(expressionType, leftOperand, rightOperand);
            }
            else
            {
                if (ruleConditionDetails.ConditionOperatorToApply == "Contains")
                {
                    ruleConditionDetails.ParameterValue = ruleConditionDetails.ParameterValue.ToString().Split(',').ToList();
                    operandType = Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]");
                    methodInfo = operandType.GetMethod(ruleConditionDetails.ConditionOperatorToApply);
                    var rightOperand = Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(ruleConditionDetails.ParameterValue, operandType));
                    expression = Expression.Call(rightOperand, methodInfo, leftOperand);
                }
            }
            return expression;
        }

        private static string GetExpressionOperator(string expressionOperator)
        {
            string tempOperator = null;
            switch (expressionOperator)
            {
                case "==":
                    tempOperator = "Equal";
                    break;
                case ">":
                    tempOperator = "GreaterThan";
                    break;
                case ">=":
                    tempOperator = "GreaterThanOrEqual";
                    break;
                case "<":
                    tempOperator = "LessThan";
                    break;
                case "<=":
                    tempOperator = "LessThanOrEqual";
                    break;
                case "!=":
                    tempOperator = "NotEqual";
                    break;
                case "IN":
                    tempOperator = "Contains";
                    break;
                default:
                    tempOperator = expressionOperator;
                    break;
            }
            return tempOperator;
        }
    }


   public class RuleCondition
    {
        public int RuleId { get; set; }
        public List<RuleConditionDetails> RuleConditionDetails { get; set; }
        public List<RuleOutput> RuleConditionOutput { get; set; }
    }

    public class RuleConditionDetails
    {
        public string RuleParameter { get; set; }
        public string ConditionOperator { get; set; }
        public object ParameterValue { get; set; }
        public string ConditionOperatorToApply { get; set; }
    }

    public class RuleOutput
    {
        public string RuleParameter { get; set; }
        public object ParameterValue { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 

            Dictionary<string, object> keyValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            keyValues.Add("Parameter1", "XYZ");
            keyValues.Add("Parameter2", 999);

            var rules = GetRuleCondtions();

            IList<PropertyDescriptor> propertyDescriptors = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();
            foreach (var item in keyValues)
            {
                var valueType = item.Value == null ? typeof(string) : item.Value.GetType();
                var propertyDescriptor = new PropertyDescriptor(item.Key, valueType);
                propertyDescriptors.Add(propertyDescriptor);
            }

            DynamicClassBuilder dynamicClassBuilder = new DynamicClassBuilder("RuleEngineInputData", propertyDescriptors);
            var ruleInputDataObject = dynamicClassBuilder.CreateObject();


            RuleEngine.RunRule<Object>(rules, ruleInputDataObject);


            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static IList<RuleCondition> GetRuleCondtions()
        {
            IList<RuleCondition> conditons = new List<RuleCondition>();

            conditons.Add(new RuleCondition()
            {
                RuleConditionDetails = new List<RuleConditionDetails>()
                {
                    new RuleConditionDetails()
                    {
                        RuleParameter = "Parameter1",
                        ConditionOperator = "==",
                        ParameterValue = "XYZ"
                    },
                    new RuleConditionDetails()
                    {
                        RuleParameter = "Parameter2",
                        ConditionOperator = "==",
                        ParameterValue = "999"
                    },
                },

            });

            return conditons;
        }
    }

// Code to create type at runtime
public class DynamicClassBuilder
    {
        AssemblyName asemblyName = null;
        IEnumerable<PropertyDescriptor> propertyDescriptors = null;

        public DynamicClassBuilder(string ClassName, IEnumerable<PropertyDescriptor> propertyDescriptors)
        {
            this.asemblyName = new AssemblyName(ClassName);
            this.propertyDescriptors = propertyDescriptors;
        }

        public Type CreateType()
        {
            // Create the type builder for creating the class
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = this.GetDynamicTypeBuilder();

            // Create the constructor inside the class
            CreateConstructor(typeBuilder);

            // Create the properties inside the class
            foreach (var propertyDescriptor in propertyDescriptors)
            {
                CreateProperty(typeBuilder, propertyDescriptor.PropertyName, propertyDescriptor.PropertyType);
            }

            // Create class
            Type type = typeBuilder.CreateTypeInfo();

            return type;
        }

        public object CreateObject()
        {
            // Create the type builder for creating the class
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = this.GetDynamicTypeBuilder();

            // Create the constructor inside the class
            CreateConstructor(typeBuilder);

            // Create the properties inside the class
            foreach (var propertyDescriptor in propertyDescriptors)
            {
                CreateProperty(typeBuilder, propertyDescriptor.PropertyName, propertyDescriptor.PropertyType);
            }

            // Create class
            Type type = typeBuilder.CreateTypeInfo();

            return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }
        private TypeBuilder GetDynamicTypeBuilder()
        {
            AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(this.asemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(this.asemblyName.FullName
                                , TypeAttributes.Public |
                                TypeAttributes.Class |
                                TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
                                TypeAttributes.AnsiClass |
                                TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit |
                                TypeAttributes.AutoLayout
                                , null);

            //typeBuilder.SetParent(typeof(RuleEngineInputDataBase));
            return typeBuilder;
        }
        private void CreateConstructor(TypeBuilder typeBuilder)
        {
            typeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);
        }
        private void CreateProperty(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
        {
            FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField("_" + propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);

            PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);
            MethodBuilder getPropMthdBldr = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
            ILGenerator getILGenerator = getPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();

            getILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            getILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
            getILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            MethodBuilder setMethodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_" + propertyName,
                  MethodAttributes.Public |
                  MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
                  MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
                  null, new[] { propertyType });

            ILGenerator setILGenerator = setMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
            Label modifyProperty = setILGenerator.DefineLabel();
            Label exitSet = setILGenerator.DefineLabel();

            setILGenerator.MarkLabel(modifyProperty);
            setILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            setILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            setILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);

            setILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
            setILGenerator.MarkLabel(exitSet);
            setILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getPropMthdBldr);
            propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setMethodBuilder);
        }

        public object SetPropertyValues(object accessor, IDictionary<string, object> ruleInputData)
        {
            Type accessorType = accessor.GetType();
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in accessorType.GetProperties())
            {
                object propertyValue = null;
                if (ruleInputData.TryGetValue(propertyInfo.Name, out propertyValue))
                {
                    if (propertyInfo.CanRead)
                    {
                        propertyValue = Convert.ChangeType(propertyValue, propertyInfo.PropertyType);
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(accessor, propertyValue);
                    }
                }
            }
            return accessor;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found few issues. First of all, methods should not be generic. You set `T` to `object` anyway. Instead you should get entity type from `ruleInputDataObject` (`ruleInputDataObject.GetType()`).
Another problem is the way you're creating lambda in `CompileRule` method. You pass want to have lambda with `Func<object, bool>` signature and access properties from generated type. This won't work unless you cast `parameterExpression` to entity type.

Here is fixed code:

```
namespace RuleEngine
{
    public class PropertyDescriptor
    {
        public string PropertyName { get; }
        public Type PropertyType { get; }

        public PropertyDescriptor(string propertyName, Type propertyType)
        {
            PropertyName = propertyName;
            PropertyType = propertyType;
        }
    }

    public class RuleEngine
    {
        public static IEnumerable<RuleOutput> RunRule(IEnumerable<RuleCondition> rules, object targetEntity)
        {
            Type entityType = targetEntity.GetType();
            IEnumerable<RuleOutput> ruleOutput = null;
            foreach (var rule in rules)
            {
                var ruleDetails = rule.RuleConditionDetails;
                rule.RuleConditionDetails.ForEach((item) =>
                {
                    item.ConditionOperatorToApply = GetExpressionOperator(item.ConditionOperator);
                });
                var compiledRules = CompileRule(rule.RuleConditionDetails, entityType);

                var foundMatchingRule = compiledRules.All(ruleTemp => ruleTemp(targetEntity));
                if (foundMatchingRule)
                {
                    ruleOutput = rule.RuleConditionOutput;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return ruleOutput;
        }

        private static List<Func<object, bool>> CompileRule(List<RuleConditionDetails> ruleConditionDetailsList,
            Type entityType)
        {
            var compiledRules = new List<Func<object, bool>>();
            ruleConditionDetailsList.ForEach(ruleConditionDetails =>
            {
                var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
                var entityExpression = Expression.Convert(parameterExpression, entityType);
                var binaryExpression = BuildBinaryExpression(ruleConditionDetails, entityExpression, entityType);

                compiledRules.Add(
                    Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>(binaryExpression, parameterExpression).Compile());
            });
            return compiledRules;
        }

        private static Expression BuildBinaryExpression(RuleConditionDetails ruleConditionDetails,
            Expression parameterExpression, Type entityType)
        {
            Expression expression = null;
            var leftOperand = MemberExpression.Property(parameterExpression, ruleConditionDetails.RuleParameter);

            ExpressionType expressionType;
            Type operandType = null;
            MethodInfo methodInfo = null;

            if (ExpressionType.TryParse(ruleConditionDetails.ConditionOperatorToApply, out expressionType))
            {
                operandType = entityType.GetProperty(ruleConditionDetails.RuleParameter).PropertyType;
                var rightOperand =
                    Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(ruleConditionDetails.ParameterValue, operandType));
                expression = Expression.MakeBinary(expressionType, leftOperand, rightOperand);
            }
            else
            {
                if (ruleConditionDetails.ConditionOperatorToApply == "Contains")
                {
                    ruleConditionDetails.ParameterValue =
                        ruleConditionDetails.ParameterValue.ToString().Split(',').ToList();
                    operandType = Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]");
                    methodInfo = operandType.GetMethod(ruleConditionDetails.ConditionOperatorToApply);
                    var rightOperand =
                        Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(ruleConditionDetails.ParameterValue, operandType));
                    expression = Expression.Call(rightOperand, methodInfo, leftOperand);
                }
            }

            return expression;
        }

        private static string GetExpressionOperator(string expressionOperator)
        {
            string tempOperator = null;
            switch (expressionOperator)
            {
                case "==":
                    tempOperator = "Equal";
                    break;
                case ">":
                    tempOperator = "GreaterThan";
                    break;
                case ">=":
                    tempOperator = "GreaterThanOrEqual";
                    break;
                case "<":
                    tempOperator = "LessThan";
                    break;
                case "<=":
                    tempOperator = "LessThanOrEqual";
                    break;
                case "!=":
                    tempOperator = "NotEqual";
                    break;
                case "IN":
                    tempOperator = "Contains";
                    break;
                default:
                    tempOperator = expressionOperator;
                    break;
            }

            return tempOperator;
        }
    }

    public class RuleCondition
    {
        public int RuleId { get; set; }
        public List<RuleConditionDetails> RuleConditionDetails { get; set; }
        public List<RuleOutput> RuleConditionOutput { get; set; }
    }

    public class RuleConditionDetails
    {
        public string RuleParameter { get; set; }
        public string ConditionOperator { get; set; }
        public object ParameterValue { get; set; }
        public string ConditionOperatorToApply { get; set; }
    }

    public class RuleOutput
    {
        public string RuleParameter { get; set; }
        public object ParameterValue { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> keyValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            keyValues.Add("Parameter1", "XYZ");
            keyValues.Add("Parameter2", 999);

            var rules = GetRuleCondtions();

            IList<PropertyDescriptor> propertyDescriptors = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();
            foreach (var item in keyValues)
            {
                var valueType = item.Value == null ? typeof(string) : item.Value.GetType();
                var propertyDescriptor = new PropertyDescriptor(item.Key, valueType);
                propertyDescriptors.Add(propertyDescriptor);
            }

            DynamicClassBuilder dynamicClassBuilder =
                new DynamicClassBuilder("RuleEngineInputData", propertyDescriptors);
            var ruleInputDataObject = dynamicClassBuilder.CreateObject();


            RuleEngine.RunRule(rules, ruleInputDataObject);


            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static IList<RuleCondition> GetRuleCondtions()
        {
            IList<RuleCondition> conditons = new List<RuleCondition>();

            conditons.Add(new RuleCondition()
            {
                RuleConditionDetails = new List<RuleConditionDetails>()
                {
                    new RuleConditionDetails()
                    {
                        RuleParameter = "Parameter1",
                        ConditionOperator = "==",
                        ParameterValue = "XYZ"
                    },
                    new RuleConditionDetails()
                    {
                        RuleParameter = "Parameter2",
                        ConditionOperator = "==",
                        ParameterValue = "999"
                    },
                },

            });

            return conditons;
        }
    }

// Code to create type at runtime
    public class DynamicClassBuilder
    {
        AssemblyName asemblyName = null;
        IEnumerable<PropertyDescriptor> propertyDescriptors = null;

        public DynamicClassBuilder(string ClassName, IEnumerable<PropertyDescriptor> propertyDescriptors)
        {
            this.asemblyName = new AssemblyName(ClassName);
            this.propertyDescriptors = propertyDescriptors;
        }

        public Type CreateType()
        {
            // Create the type builder for creating the class
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = this.GetDynamicTypeBuilder();

            // Create the constructor inside the class
            CreateConstructor(typeBuilder);

            // Create the properties inside the class
            foreach (var propertyDescriptor in propertyDescriptors)
            {
                CreateProperty(typeBuilder, propertyDescriptor.PropertyName, propertyDescriptor.PropertyType);
            }

            // Create class
            Type type = typeBuilder.CreateTypeInfo();

            return type;
        }

        public object CreateObject()
        {
            // Create the type builder for creating the class
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = this.GetDynamicTypeBuilder();

            // Create the constructor inside the class
            CreateConstructor(typeBuilder);

            // Create the properties inside the class
            foreach (var propertyDescriptor in propertyDescriptors)
            {
                CreateProperty(typeBuilder, propertyDescriptor.PropertyName, propertyDescriptor.PropertyType);
            }

            // Create class
            Type type = typeBuilder.CreateTypeInfo();

            return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }

        private TypeBuilder GetDynamicTypeBuilder()
        {
            AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder =
                AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(this.asemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(this.asemblyName.FullName
                , TypeAttributes.Public |
                  TypeAttributes.Class |
                  TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
                  TypeAttributes.AnsiClass |
                  TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit |
                  TypeAttributes.AutoLayout
                , null);

            //typeBuilder.SetParent(typeof(RuleEngineInputDataBase));
            return typeBuilder;
        }

        private void CreateConstructor(TypeBuilder typeBuilder)
        {
            typeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
                                                 MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);
        }

        private void CreateProperty(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
        {
            FieldBuilder fieldBuilder =
                typeBuilder.DefineField("_" + propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);

            PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder =
                typeBuilder.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);
            MethodBuilder getPropMthdBldr = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName,
                MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, propertyType,
                Type.EmptyTypes);
            ILGenerator getILGenerator = getPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();

            getILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            getILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
            getILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            MethodBuilder setMethodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_" + propertyName,
                MethodAttributes.Public |
                MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
                MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
                null, new[] {propertyType});

            ILGenerator setILGenerator = setMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
            Label modifyProperty = setILGenerator.DefineLabel();
            Label exitSet = setILGenerator.DefineLabel();

            setILGenerator.MarkLabel(modifyProperty);
            setILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            setILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            setILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);

            setILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
            setILGenerator.MarkLabel(exitSet);
            setILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getPropMthdBldr);
            propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setMethodBuilder);
        }

        public object SetPropertyValues(object accessor, IDictionary<string, object> ruleInputData)
        {
            Type accessorType = accessor.GetType();
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in accessorType.GetProperties())
            {
                object propertyValue = null;
                if (ruleInputData.TryGetValue(propertyInfo.Name, out propertyValue))
                {
                    if (propertyInfo.CanRead)
                    {
                        propertyValue = Convert.ChangeType(propertyValue, propertyInfo.PropertyType);
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(accessor, propertyValue);
                    }
                }
            }

            return accessor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: was not aware of Expression.Convert method. Thanks for the answer.